# DEP0800: Cannot deploy UWP app after upgrading to VS 2015 Update 3

Tags: .net, visual-studio, uwp

I am having a very hard time getting my UWP app to deploy in debug mode after upgrading to VS 2015 Update 3.

> 2>Checking whether required frameworks are installed...
>   2>Framework: Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug/x86, app package version 14.0.24210.0 is not currently installed.
>   2>Framework: Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0/x86, app package version 1.0.23819.0 is not currently installed.
>   2>Framework: Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug/x86, app package version 14.0.24210.0 is not currently installed.
>   2>Installing missing frameworks...
>   2>DEP0800 : The required framework "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs\14.0\.\AppX\Debug\x86\Microsoft.VCLibs.x86.Debug.14.00.appx" failed to install. 
>   2>error 0x80070003: Windows cannot create the AppContainer profile for the Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug_14.0.24210.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe package.

This path doesn't exist because of the '.\' inbetween; as a result I updated the SDKManifest.xml file in the 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs\14.0\' folder to remove the '.\'; but am still unable to deploy the app.

I've already tried reinstalling and then reparing VS, but to no avail (and I really don't want to reinstall my OS -_-)

Any ideas as to what might be wrong and how I could fix it?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and fixed it by installing the missing appx through Powershell as admin.

```
Add-AppxPackage "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs\14.0\Appx\Debug\x86\Microsoft.VCLibs.x86.Debug.14.00.appx"
```

Comment: Just in case somebody needs it: I had to close Visual Studio and other applications to install the missing appx.

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues after the SP3 upgrade also. For me, making sure that the configuration manager was building all my projects and deploying what I expected it to deploy for the build and target I expected fixed my issues.

You can check this by Right clicking on Solution -> Properties -> Configuration

Comment: The root problem turned out to be that the SDKs weren't registered right in the Windows registry (Probably got messed up when upgrading from one version of VS to another). 
I had to uninstall my VS, clean my registry and reinstall it again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For me it helped starting the windows search service during installing the appx directly. afterwards I could deactivate Window Search Service again.