# Microsoft Advertising Xaml x64 - failed to install

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

I am develop an UWP app, that has ads (with Microsoft Advertising SDK for XAML) and was now preparing an update when I do "Create App Packages" is giving me this error:

`DEP0800 : The required framework "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.Advertising.Xaml\10.0\.\AppX\x64\Microsoft.Advertising.Xaml.x64.10.0.appx" failed to install.`

But this only happens on x64. In x86 and ARM this error does not happen!
And this error never appeared, and I did not make any changes I do not understand why this error just started to appear now.

I already tried to install it manually and it does not work either.

Why does this error appear? How do I solve it?

Comment: Are you using a 64bit os?

Comment: Exit VS, and manually install the `Microsoft.Advertising.Xaml.x64.10.0.appx` from PowerShell, like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42161136/815938) suggests. Does it help?

Comment: Since you failed to install the x64 `Microsoft.Advertising.Xaml.x64.10.0.appx`, you can reinstall the [Microsoft Advertising SDK](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AdMediator.MicrosoftAdvertisingSDK) to install the advertising framework you need..